# How to display my website in a search engine with menus and links displayed in the search results

Tags: search-engine, meta-tags

If you search for "richfaces" in google.com, the first result will be about www.jboss.org/richfaces. You may watch there that links (menus) like "Downloads", "Demos", "Documentations" are also displayed. How to have these links displayed in the search results?

(The "description" meta tag not enough I hope)

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to make Google show links to your site (they will do this if they deem your site is relevant enough to warrant providing this feature). However, you can remove these links if they are present, if they are inappropriate.

See http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

These are called Google Site Links. Google is pretty tight-lipped about how this feature is automated, but there are a handful of HTML5 tags which are supposed to help make search engines smarter. You can read more about them at [O'Reilly's *Dive Into HTML5*](http://diveintohtml5.info/extensibility.html)  website. Especially interesting are the "Google Rich Snippets", though they're not exactly what you're looking for.

It might help to put those links in the HTML5 nav tags, like

```
<nav>Home About FAQ</nav>
```

and I've heard it tossed around that the site navigation should be an unordered list, but I don't know how true that is. Still, it couldn't hurt to do it that way and style the list with CSS.